# What would produce these strange characters in a DateTime to String conversion?

Tags: .net, datetime

I have some code which records a `DateTime` in some output files:

```
 DateTime dateTime = DateTime::Now;
 String^ value = String::Format("{0} {1}", dateTime.ToShortDateString(), dateTime.ToLongTimeString());
```

...which is apparently giving some odd outputs on a customers machine:

```
2014-12-16 오전 12:00:00
```

What might be causing those additional characters to appear there?

Comment: That is Korean for "AM". But I find it hard to understand why they find that strange, if they have there language set to Korean on their machine in the first place. Do you mean your code isn't expecting it?

Comment: I've double-checked and they are indeed Korean so that would fit entirely.

Comment: So what is the actual problem? Is it causing your program to fail/crash at some point?

Comment: The problem is that it's not displaying the date/time in the expected format and the customer would prefer in the anticipated `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` form.

Comment: In that case you have your answers below for that. I'm just struggling as to why your Korean customer is so confused by it, but that's not really important I guess

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's fairly reasonable if the user is in a different locale - you should ask your customer what their system locale is. Use the invariant culture if you want a machine-readable format. For example:

```
String^ value = dateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss",
                                  CultureInfo::InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 3):

Those characters mean "forenoon" in Korean according to [Wikipedia](http://ko.wikipedia.org/wiki/%EC%98%A4%EC%A0%84) (see English link), so I guess it's in the client's regional settings, which are represented through (presumably) `ToLongTimeString()`.

Answer (score 1):

By using the [CultureInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class you can always maintain a constant date format. Even after the page or file is accessed in different location.  By defining as below

For Ex :

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");
```

Comment: If only the US date format wasn't so illogical... it's a bit like displaying a list to a user, but forgetting to apply any useful sort order to it :/

Comment: @musefan If only one could format such a date into a format more relevant for the person viewing it...

Comment: yes.... I was just making a general comment about how useless I think the US date format is. A perfect example of how one bad decision can affect an entire planet for years to come...